# How to add multiple buttons to a window? C#

Tags: c#, button, controls

I am currently writing a game the requires a shop. I am planing in making 1 button open the shop/show all the buttons of things you can buy. I am currently having a hard time adding the button to the actual window. the "contorls" function isn't showing up as a option.

```
for (int i = 0; i < weaponsList.Count; i++)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
            newButton.Content = weaponsList[i].WeaponName += weaponsList[i].MinDamage += weaponsList[i].MaxDamage += weaponsList[i].Cost;
            newButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            newButton.Width = 502;
            newButton.Height = 78;
        }
```

The for loop is so that it will keep adding buttons for the number of weapons. i have tried doing the controls thing but it hasn't worked.

Comment: You put all buttons in same position. You cover lower buttons?

Comment: do it with: this.Controls.Add(newButton); dont forget to use a tablelayoutpanel :-)

Answer (score 0):

You put all buttons in same position. If you want see all buttons, you must have different positions. Quick good solution is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weaponsList.Count; i++)
{
  Button newButton = new Button();
  newButton.Name = Convert.ToString(i);
  newButton.Content = weaponsList[i].WeaponName += weaponsList[i].MinDamage += weaponsList[i].MaxDamage += weaponsList[i].Cost;
  newButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
  newButton.Width = 502+10*i;
  newButton.Height = 78+10*i;
}
```